# Burn the [today] tag

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

Can we please burninate the [today](/questions/tagged/today) tag? I just happened to realize the such a tag even existed when I saw the [suggested tag wiki edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3627242) for it. And most surprising the wiki content itself had the word *today* mentioned in it.

So can we please do away with this [today](/questions/tagged/today) tag?

Comment: Can we please get this done *[today]*?

Comment: we will do it tomorrow :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I retaged all questions.

I applied [date](/questions/tagged/date) instead of [today](/questions/tagged/today) wherever applicable.